# Try to check if there is something in clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I looking for best way to check if something there is in the clipboard using "pywin32"

for instance I want to clear the clipboard, after make "ctrl + c" and than check if variable 'output' is still empty or not. If clipboard is not empty macros works, but if clipboard is empty it shows next error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Desktop\Python_Learning\Check if empry script.py", line 13, in 
output = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
TypeError: Specified clipboard format is not available"

I cannot find anything in google, so decide to ask here (about one weak learn codding), hope someone can help to fix it.

```
`
import win32clipboard
import pyautogui as pya

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
output = win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

print(output)
pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
output = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

if output is None:
    print("there is nothing")
else:
    print("There is something")

print(output)
`
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure EmptyClipboard() just clears the clipboard

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can use a try/catch statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
try:
    output = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
except TypeError:
    output = None
```

I don't know how the win32clipboard module works but I've seen people use a try/except statement with it